# Parallelization - BubbleSort Open-MP C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize the bubble sort algorithm using Open-MP, C++ and the pipeline approach. The following code makes sense to me, but it does'n work properly. It only sorts subarrays with (Input_Size)/(Number_of_threads).
The "critical" keyword wouldn't organize the thread execution order so the final array would bem sorted? I also tried the "atomic" keyword, but it doesn't seem to work, and the compiler keeps returning the following error `invalid form of ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘;’ token`

Ex.: the array 9 4 19 9 5 4 5 6 20 18, using 3 threads, gives me the array 4 9 9 4 5 5 19 6 18 20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int *readFile(int num,ifstream &ifs)
{
  int *array;
  char charac[255];  
  if(ifs.good())
  {   
    array = new int [num];
    for(int i =0;i<num;i++)
    {
      ifs>>array[i];
      //cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

void bubbleP(int *a,int size,int nT)
{   
  int slice = size/nT;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(nT)
  {
    int index = omp_get_thread_num();
    int temp;   
    for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
      for(int j=index*slice; j<(index+1)*slice; j++)
      {
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
        {   
          temp=a[j];
          #pragma omp atomic
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
        }
      }
    }
    printf("Thread number: %d\n\n", index);
  }
  if (size <= 30)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
      printf("Array: %d\n", a[i]);
  }
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
   int *a;
   int size;
   ifstream ifs;
   ifs.open(argv[1]);
   int nThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
   ifs>>size;
   printf("Reading file: %s\n", argv[1]);
   a = readFile(size,ifs);
   bubbleP(a,size,nThreads);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at what you're doing. Your `bubbleP` function tells it to sort the subarrays, which it does just fine. But nothing in your code is telling it to merge the sorted subarrays. Bubblesort isn't particularly amenable to parallel processing in general, and a parallel version doesn't really gain you much in the face of the O(n^2) complexity. Parallelization gives you linear increases in speed, whereas bubblesort's time requirement increases quadratically. That's a losing proposition every time. You're better off parallelizing shell sort, quick sort, or merge sort.

Comment: That's a test. The sort algorithm must be O(n^2).

Comment: Well, here's one way to do it, provided you have a whole lot of processors: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/bubbleSort.htm. You can of course do it with fewer processors; it'll just take a little longer. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997684/c-openmp-parallel-bubble-sort, which your question is probably considered a duplicate of.